# Command line cross plaftorm screen recording & conversion to FLV

Tags: screen-capture

My goal is very simple - use a command line (standalone exe) that can record desktop activities & dump out a compressed FLV file. I looked at http://camstudio.org/blog/camstudio-command-line-v01-released but there are couple of problems with it - 1) it windows only & 2) I couldn't figure out how to dump our flv instead its output was a huge avi file even for a 30 second session.

Is there a software that allows interaction with it through command line (so that I don't have to bring up a GUI) and work on at least Mac & Windows?

Comment: I think a question about finding the right application for the job (command line or otherwise) may be more at home on Superuser...

Comment: Actually this is for automation purposes. We have our own homegrown automation framework & when it kicks off I'd like to record the whole session & just dump out an FLV, which gets embedded to the reports web page.